# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: delphi, api

Tenho um método em DELPHI que executa um Post utilizando `TIDHTTP`. Na primeira vez ele funciona normalmente, porém apartir da segunda ele me apresenta o erro: `exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`
o método está assim:

```
function TApiAPE.postJson(uri: string; sJsonToSend: string): TRetornoAPE;
  var JsonToSend: TStringStream;
      sResponse: string;
      jsonObj: TJSONObject;
begin
  result.ok := false;
  result.mensagem  := '';
  result.idRetorno := 0;

  JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create( Utf8Encode( sJsonToSend ) );
  try
    FHTTPClient.Request.Method := 'POST';
    try
      sResponse := FHTTPClient.Post(uri, JsonToSend);  //<<< AQUI ELE APRESENTA O ERRO NA SEGUNDA CHAMADA AO METODO
      if FHTTPClient.ResponseCode=200 then
      begin
        //{
        //  "MensagemRetorno": "Requisição feita com sucesso",
        //  "idGerado": 510387
        //}
        jsonObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sResponse),0) as TJSONObject;
        if jsonObj.Get('idGerado')<>nil then
        begin
          result.ok := true;
          result.mensagem  := jsonObj.GetValue('MensagemRetorno').Value ;
          result.idRetorno := StrToIntDef( jsonObj.GetValue('idGerado').Value,0 );
        end;
      end;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        result.codigoRetorno := FHTTPClient.ResponseCode;
        FHTTPClient.Disconnect;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    JsonToSend.free;
  end;
end;
```

Alguem sabe o que pode ser? o conteudo da variavel `sJsonToSend` é igual ao anterior

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amigo, salva seu Json em Texto e use o site https://jsonlint.com/ para validar seu arquivo Json, em seguida use Postman para enviar a requisição pro seu servidor, assim você isola, e saberá se é o componente, ou de fato o Json que está sendo enviado, geralmente o retorno 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', significa que o Json enviado está fora de padrão, seja um numero inteiro, uma data, uma string errada.

Comment: Valeu companheiro, seguindo sua dica descobri por exigência da API preciso informar um ID diferenciado a cada requisição. Resolvido